# Getting error in Excel to MongoDB JSON convert using Java

Tags: java, mongodb

```
package company;


import java.io.File;

public class MyFinalProject {


    public   String readExcel(String filePath, int sheetNumber) {

        String jsonCartList = null;
        try {
                File f = new File( filePath );
                Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(f);
                Sheet mySheet = wb.getSheetAt(sheetNumber);
                int rowCount = 0;
                List<Map<String, String>> hmap = new ArrayList<Map<String, 
                String>>();
                List<String> keyList = new ArrayList<String>();
                List<String> valueList = new ArrayList<String>();
                for(Iterator<Row> rowIterator = mySheet.rowIterator() ; 
               rowIterator.hasNext(); )
                {
                    for(Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = ((Row)rowIterator.next()).cellIterator(); cellIterator.hasNext();) 
                    {                       
                        if (rowCount == 0) {
//                          System.out.println(((Cell)cellIterator.next()).toString());
//                          System.out.println("\n");
                            keyList.add(((Cell)cellIterator.next()).toString());                            
                        } else if (rowCount > 0) {
//                          System.out.println(((Cell)cellIterator.next()).toString());
//                          System.out.println("\n");
                            valueList.add(((Cell)cellIterator.next()).toString());                          

                        }
                    }
                    rowCount += 1;
                }
//              System.out.println("\n");
//              System.out.println(keyList);
//              System.out.println(valueList);
                for (int vCount=0; vCount<valueList.size(); vCount=vCount+keyList.size() ) {
                    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    for (int kCount=0; kCount<keyList.size(); kCount++ ) {
                        map.put(keyList.get(kCount), valueList.get(kCount+vCount));
                        System.out.println("\n");
//                      System.out.println(map.toString());
                    }
                    hmap.add(map);
                }

//              System.out.println(hmap.toString());
// create a new Gson instance
                Gson gson = new Gson();
// convert your list to json
                jsonCartList = gson.toJson(hmap);
//              System.out.println("jsonList: " + jsonCartList);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return jsonCartList;
    }
}
```

the mongodb connection page is

```
package company;

import com.mongodb.DB;

public class MongodbConn 
{


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyFinalProject obj = new MyFinalProject();

        try {

            Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
            DB db = mongo.getDB("yourdb");

            DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("Test");



            String inputJson = obj.readExcel("C://Users//Prativa Mondal//Documents//Book1.xlsx", 0);
            System.out.println("jsonList: " +inputJson);


            //convert JSON to DBObject directly

            DBObject[] dbObject = (DBObject[]) JSON
                    .parse(inputJson);


            collection.insert(dbObject);

            DBCursor cursorDoc = collection.find();
            while (cursorDoc.hasNext()) {

                System.out.println(cursorDoc.next());


            }



        System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MongoException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

error is

jsonList: [{"ROLLNO.":"111.0","ADDRESS":"BURDWAN","TITLE":"MONDAL","PHNO.":"9932769638,7908307232","NAME":"PRATIVA","AGE":"23.0"},{"ROLLNO.":"222.0","ADDRESS":"ASANSOL","TITLE":"MONDAL","PHNO.":"8743562345","NAME":"PRASITA","AGE":"24.0"},{"ROLLNO.":"333.0","ADDRESS":"BISHNUPUR","TITLE":"DEY","PHNO.":"8965247535,8963254712,9965885422","NAME":"DOLAN","AGE":"25.0"},{"ROLLNO.":"444.0","ADDRESS":"KOLKATA","TITLE":"DEY","PHNO.":"","NAME":"MADHUMITA","AGE":"26.0"},{"ROLLNO.":"555.0","ADDRESS":"HYDERABAD","TITLE":"MONDAL","PHNO.":"8574996325","NAME":"RIYA","AGE":"27.0"},{"ROLLNO.":"666.0","ADDRESS":"MUMBAI","TITLE":"CHATTERJEE","PHNO.":"7896542358,8965745236,9875441222","NAME":"PRIYA","AGE":"28.0"},{"ROLLNO.":"777.0","ADDRESS":"DELHI","TITLE":"ROY","PHNO.":"8896574896,7896524899","NAME":"DEEPALI","AGE":"29.0"},{"ROLLNO.":"888.0","ADDRESS":"BHUPAL","TITLE":"SHU","PHNO.":"9978542159","NAME":"SANCHITA","AGE":"30.0"}]

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BasicBSONList can only work with numeric keys, not: [_id]

and its not showing into mongodb

Comment: Pretty self explanatory error message as the keys clearly need to be a "string". You need to do something about those numeric keys before you attempt to insert

Comment: i have inserted my code. now plz help me.thank you